# method does not override or implement a method from a supertype - Reactnative

Tags: java, android, react-native, realm

I am trying to run my react native app on an android emulator by running `react-native run-android` it brings this error `RealmReactPackage.java:18: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^`

Please what may be causing this error

**RealmReactPackage.java**

```
package io.realm.react;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class RealmReactPackage implements ReactPackage {
@Override
public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.<NativeModule>singletonList(new RealmReactModule(reactContext));
}

@Override     //line 18
public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[com.facebook.react.ReactPackage](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactPackage.java) does not contains createJSModules() method. You should not annotate it with @Override.